# Python - parsing through a variable for desired data

Tags: python, parsing, pyodbc

this should be pretty simple.
I'm writing a program to pull data from a database to be stored in a variable and passed on to another program. I have it working to connect to the db and run the query to pull the data, which is returned in a new line for each column. I would like to parse through this output to store only the columns I need into separate variables to be imported by another python program. Please note that the print(outbound) part is just there for testing purposes.

Here's the function:

```
def pullData():
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('UID='+dbUser+';PWD='+dbPassword+';DSN='+dbHost)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()

    #run query to pull the newest sms message
    outbound = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM WKM_SMS_outbound ORDER BY id DESC")
    table = cursor.fetchone()
    for outbound in table:
        print(outbound)

    #close connection
    cnxn.close()
```

and here's the sample output from the query that I would like to parse through- as it's currently being stored in variable outbound. (NOTE) This is not 1 column. This is one ROW. Each new line is a new column in the db... this is just how it's being returned and formatted when I run the program.

[image]

Comment: did you consider to create an empty dict an fill it while you iterating over table ?

Comment: I think you need to provide a sample output (and what you tried!) as I see only one column, and don't understand what you expect. And maybe you could just not select * but only the required columns!?

Comment: I did not consider a dictionary, I considered an array- however i'm still learning python and am not sure how exactly the parsing would be done. However, thank you for the suggestion and I will start looking into python dictionaries!

Comment: B. Go- That is a sample output. That is not one column, it is one row (as the query only fetches the newest row entered in the db). Each new line in the output you see above is a value from a different column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the best way you can achieve this:
(Considering that your **table** variable returns as list)

```py
# Lets say until here you've done your queries
collection = {}
for index,outbound in enumerate(table):
   key_name = "key{0}".format(index)
   collection[key_name] = outbound

print(collection)
```

## OUTPUT Expected:

```
{
    "key1" : 6932921,
    "key2" : 303794,
    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```

And then what you can do to access it from another python file by importing the **collection** variable by adding **return collection** on your **pulldata** function

On the other python file it will be simple just to:

```py
from your_file_name import collection # considering they are on the same directory
```